# Changing URLs for taxonomies and CPT

Tags: custom-taxonomy, urls

I have two taxonomies for my custom post type: `location` and `price-range`.

`location` is hierarchical: `city > region > suburb` ... `price-range` isn't.

When a user goes into a URL like `ww.page.com/location/{city}` I show a special homepage built for that city.

In every other case (`www.page.com/location/{region}`, `www.page.com/location/{suburb}`, `www.page.com/price-range/{price}`) the user gets redirected to a category pace showing a list of custom posts tagged with that term.

However, for SEO purposes I want the URLS to be slightly different. For the homepages (`www.page.com/location/{city}`) I want it to be `www.page.com/{city}` and for the rest of the cases I want `www.page.com/{city}/{term}`, where term could be any region, suburb, or price-range.

When a user goes into `www.page.com/price-range/{price}` I have the city stored in a session variable and this allows me to query custom posts with a specific price-range within the correct city. This behaviour is already implemented. All I want is to remove the taxonomy name from the URL (`location` or `price-range`) and replace it with the city I have stored in the session variable.

Is this possible? By doing so, I don't want to change the way Wordpress looks up the correct template file. That already works the way it should. I just want to change the URLS to make them a bit prettier.

Also, my custom post type is called `listing`. To see the details of a particular listing, I have to use the URL `www.page.com/listing/{listing_name}`. Again, I would like to have something like `www.page.com/{city}/{listing_name}`

Thanks in advance. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From my point of view, the URL changes you have in mind doesn't affect to SEO, at least as a direct factor, maybe it can affect if that change super-charge the user experience in your site and after some time the user engagement revert on the SEO, but I don't think you get that result by changing the URL in that way. Apart to that opinion, your requeriments would need a lot of job and testing; you need to narrow down your question to specific issues to be answerable here.